# How to publish npm packages from a workspace in a transaction?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-package, npm-publish

I have a monorepo workspace with several packages. I bump the version of all packages at the same time and publish them using the following command:

```
npm publish --workspace packages
```

This publishes the packages sequentially, and if the publishing of a package fails, it skips publishing the next packages. For instance, suppose I am trying to bump the version from `v1.0.0` to `v1.0.1`, and the publishing of `package3` fails. This failure causes `package{n>3}` to not get bumped, and it also does not roll back the version bumps of the previous packages.

```
package1 1.0.0 -> 1.0.1
package2 1.0.0 -> 1.0.1
package3 1.0.0 -> FAILED
package4 1.0.0 -> SKIPPED
package5 1.0.0 -> SKIPPED
```

I want all my packages to have the same version at all times. However, the current behavior leads to inconsistencies in package versions.

Is there a way I can rollback the version bumps of earlier packages in case of a failure? If not, is there a way I can configure this to run in a transaction so that publishing happens only if all succeed; otherwise, it fails for all?

---

Edit 1: It appears that this feature is not available in the `npm publish` command. I have created a [transactional-publish RFC](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/pull/696) to propose this functionality.